# Can a music band be referred to as an artist?

Tags: grammar

Is it correct to refer to a band as an artist such as 'My favourite artist is The Beatles'?

Comment: They are a group of artists known as a ***group***: *My favorite **group** is* The Beatles.

Comment: As a practical matter, pieces of recorded music are often cataloged by "name" and "artist".  When a group is responsible for the recording, then, the group name would go into the "artist" column in the catalog.  Thus there is pressure to consider the band as a group to be a (singular) "artist", whether this upsets the wordies or not.  (IOW, how "correct" does it need to be?)

Answer (score 1):

An **artist** is referred to as a single *person* according to *[dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/artist)*. You can however refer to the members of a band as **artists** like in the following [sentence:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Beatles)

> The Beatles are the best-selling music **artists** in the United States, with 178 .....